# Linux script for copying files from multiple windows machines

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, smb

Having a issue trying to make a bash script that will read ip address and usernames from a file that mount a connection to that share on windows and then copy ano file types into a new folder called the users name. 
At the moment it doesn't quite work, it makes hundreds of folders called *.ano if it can not find the windows share.

Help please

Text file:

```
192.168.0.2 user1
192.168.0.3 user2
```

bash script:

```
USER='/home/user/user.ip'
IPADDY=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' $USER)
USERNAME=$(awk '{ print $NF }' $USER)
for i in $IPADDY $USERNAME
do
    mkdir /home/user/Documents/$USERNAME
    mount -t smbfs //$IPADDY/$USERNAME /home/user/$USERNAME
    rsync -va /home/user/$USERNAME/*.ano /home/user/Documents/$USERNAME/*.ano
done
```

Hi all thanks for such a quick reply, I have change the code as follow but still get multiple files have I done something wrong here

```
    USER='/home/user/user.ip'
IPADDY=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' $USER)
USERNAME=$(awk '{ print $NF }' $USER)
while read IPADDY USERNAME; do
mkdir /home/user/Documents/$USERNAME
mount -t smbfs //$IPADDY/$USERNAME /home/user/$USERNAME
rsync -va /home/user/$USERNAME/*.ano /home/user/Documents/$USERNAME/
done < $USER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `for` command. In your script, `i` iterates over the contents of $IPADDY, *then* it iterates over the contents of $USERNAME. Meanwhile, $USERNAME inside the loop gets expanded to `user1 user2`, resulting in:

```
mkdir /home/user/Documents/user1 user2
```

The mount line becomes:

```
mount -t smbfs //192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3/user1 user2 /home/user/user1 user2
```

And so on.

Rather, loop over the file itself:

```
while read IPADDY USERNAME; do
  #awesome things here based on $IPADDY and $USERNAME
done < $USER
```

You might want to add `[[ -z $IPADDY ]] && continue` to skip over any possible blank lines in the file.

Comment: Hi all thanks for such a quick reply Hi all thanks for such a quick reply, I have change the code as follow but still get multiple files have I done something wrong here   USER='/home/user/user.ip'
IPADDY=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' $USER)
USERNAME=$(awk '{ print $NF }' $USER)
while read IPADDY USERNAME; do
mkdir /home/user/Documents/$USERNAME
mount -t smbfs //$IPADDY/$USERNAME /home/user/$USERNAME
rsync -va /home/user/$USERNAME/*.ano /home/user/Documents/$USERNAME/
done < $USER

Comment: @pepoluan thanks for your help, i've changed the code but still getting multiple files, have I done something wrong here `USER='/home/user/user.ip'
IPADDY=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' $USER)
USERNAME=$(awk '{ print $NF }' $USER)
while read IPADDY USERNAME; do
mkdir /home/user/Documents/$USERNAME
mount -t smbfs //$IPADDY/$USERNAME /home/user/$USERNAME
rsync -va /home/user/$USERNAME/*.ano /home/user/Documents/$USERNAME/
done < $USER
`

Comment: @Grimlockz you must not rsync if the mount failed; add ` &&` (space and and) behind the `mount` line. The `&&` means to execute the next command *only if* the last command returns `0` (which, in the *nix world, means success). Plus, you can drop lines 2 and 3 (the ones with `grep` and `awk`); they're no longer needed.

Comment: `USER='/home/billy/user.ip'
#IPADDY=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' $USER)
#USERNAME=$(awk '{ print $NF }' $USER)
while read IPADDY USERNAME; do
mkdir /home/billy/Documents/$USERNAME
mount ` &&` -t smbfs //$IPADDY/$USERNAME  /home/billy/$USERNAME
cp /home/billy/$USERNAME/*.ano /home/billy/Documents/$USERNAME/
done < $USER` Do you mean like this?

Comment: @pepoluan   `USER='/home/billy/user.ip'
#IPADDY=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' $USER)
#USERNAME=$(awk '{ print $NF }' $USER)
IPADDY=$USER
USERNAME=$USER
while read IPADDY USERNAME; do
' &&'
mkdir /home/billy/Documents/$USERNAME 
mount -t smbfs //$IPADDY/$USERNAME  /home/billy/$USERNAME
' &&'
rsync -va /home/billy/$USERNAME/ /home/billy/Documents/$USERNAME/
done < $USER
` I'm getting closer I think, files are being copied now, only issue now is that I have to enter password if mount exists

Comment: @Grimlockz um, the 'space and and' must *not* be within quotes. and it should be appended at the *end of the line* that begins with 'mount'. I.e., change the line to: `mount -t smbfs //$IPADDY/$USERNAME /home/billy/$USERNAME &&` and *only* that line.

Comment: @pepoluan Hey, sorry for the late reply When i try to add the && I get error on line 8 syntax error near unexpected token `done' and when I take the && away the script seems to work...

Comment: @Grimlockz are you sure you added `&&` only to the end of the `mount` line and not the `rsync` line? `&&` in bash means to execute the next command *only* if the command preceding `&&` runs successfully.

Comment: @pepoluan ahh cheers that works. The other idea I have is that I only need to rsync the ano files so would it be a good idea to use something like this rsync -rvtW --delay-updates --modify-window=1 --progress --include='*.ano' --exclude='*.*' /home/grimlockz/$USERNAME/ /home/grimlockz/Documents/$USERNAME/

Comment: @Grimlockz unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with rsync command vagaries, so I regretfully can't help you there... good luck, though :)

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you use a wildcard (`*`) for the destination files. But those files don't exist - therefore `/home/user/Documents/$USERNAME/*.ano` cannot match and rsync will create a file `*.log`.

Better do:

```
rsync -va /home/user/$USERNAME/*.ano /home/user/Documents/$USERNAME/
```